# Joining query results into one

Tags: t-sql

This is my table to track down the employees off days. This example is only for one person.

```
ID   PID     Year       OffDays       DayTypeNumber
------------------------------------------
1     1      2011       10            1
2     1      2011       5             2
3     1      2012       20            1
4     1      2012       3             2
```

I would like to write such a query that should only show one result for each year with additional column

```
Year       OffDays(1)    OffDays(2)
------------------------------------------
2011       10            5
2012       20            3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function for this:

```
select year,
  [1] [OffDays(1)],
  [2] [OffDays(2)]
from
(
  select year, offdays, daytypenumber
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(offdays)
  for daytypenumber in([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8622d/3)

Result:

```
| YEAR | OFFDAYS(1) | OFFDAYS(2) |
----------------------------------
| 2011 |         10 |          5 |
| 2012 |         20 |          3 |
```

Or you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select year,
  sum(case when daytypenumber = 1 then offdays end) [OffDays(1)],
  sum(case when daytypenumber = 2 then offdays end) [OffDays(2)]
from yourtable
group by year
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8622d/5)

If you only have two types that you are comparing, then you can use subqueries:

```
select t1.year, 
  [OffDays(1)],
  [OffDays(2)]
from
(
  select sum(offdays) [OffDays(1)], year
  from yourtable
  where daytypenumber = 1
  group by year
) t1
left join
(
  select sum(offdays) [OffDays(2)], year
  from yourtable
  where daytypenumber = 2
  group by year
) t2
  on t1.year = t2.year
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8622d/11)

The above answers will work great, if you have a known number of values for `DayTypeNumber`, but if those are unknown then you can use dynamic SQL to generate the `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DayTypeNumber) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colNames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(DayTypeNumber) 
                      +' as [OffDays('+cast(DayTypeNumber as varchar(10))+')]'
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT year,' + @colNames + ' from 
             (
                select year, offdays, daytypenumber
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(offdays)
                for daytypenumber in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8622d/17)

All of these will produce the same results:

```
| YEAR | OFFDAYS(1) | OFFDAYS(2) |
----------------------------------
| 2011 |         10 |          5 |
| 2012 |         20 |          3 |
```

Comment: I know (and hope) you will give the dynamic query in some time [like this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27669/9332)

Comment: @Kaf - That's the artifice of SQLFiddle and the knowledge of [bluefeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet?tab=answers&sort=votes). :)

Comment: dude, what did you do in here!
you are genious! thank you very much!